# TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

Laravel dusk issue

My VM site running on http://172.31.71.71:9090
and when I tried to run PHP artisan dusk

My code

```
    protected function driver()
{
    $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--headless',
        '--window-size=1920,1080',
    ]);

    return RemoteWebDriver::create(
        'http://172.31.71.71:9090', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
        )
    );
}
```

Getting error 
        PHPUnit 7.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

```
    E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

    Time: 99 ms, Memory: 16.00 MB

    There was 1 error:

    1) Tests\Browser\LoginTest::testLogin
    TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/marketplaceoffers.com/www/marketplaceoffers/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php on line 145

    /var/www/marketplaceoffers.com/www/marketplaceoffers/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/DesiredCapabilities.php:33
    /var/www/marketplaceoffers.com/www/marketplaceoffers/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:145
    /var/www/marketplaceoffers.com/www/marketplaceoffers/tests/DuskTestCase.php:37
    /var/www/marketplaceoffers.com/www/marketplaceoffers/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:192
    /var/www/marketplaceoffers.com/www/marketplaceoffers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:817
    /var/www/marketplaceoffers.com/www/marketplaceoffers/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:193
    /var/www/marketplaceoffers.com/www/marketplaceoffers/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:93
    /var/www/marketplaceoffers.com/www/marketplaceoffers/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:64
    /var/www/marketplaceoffers.com/www/marketplaceoffers/tests/Browser/LoginTest.php:21

    ERRORS!
    Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
    root@71e3381c1bc4:/var/www/marketplaceoffers.com/www/marketplaceoffers#
```

Comment: Can anyon please help on this 
https://prnt.sc/op2wlp

Answer (score 1):

change 'http://172.31.71.71:9090' to 'http://localhost:9515',

```
    return RemoteWebDriver::create(
        'http://localhost:9515',
        DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY,
            $options
        ),
    );
```

Comment: can you explain why the port change matters? If his site runs on :9090, dusk must be translating the page to :9515? But how do you tell dusk to go to the desired IP?